# How to use JSON response using list

Tags: c#, json

I have class

```
public class RootObject
{
public List<Weather> weather {get;set;}
}
public class Weather
{
public int id {get;set;}
public string description {get;set}
}
```

I check there is response, now I de-serialize the JSON and try to use data

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
                RootObject nObj = (RootObject)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
                List<Weather> list = new List<Weather>();
                list = nObj.weather;
}
```

Now I am not able to get `id` and `description` by using below line of code

```
Console.Writeline(list.id);
```

Or

```
Console.Writeline(list.description);
```

How I read data. Please help

Comment: You cannot access one element from a list like that. You have to ask yourself which element you want to access, for example `list[5].id`, or `list.First().id`.

Comment: What does the JSON string look like?

Comment: Now I get the value for id and description. But now the problem is that when i try to assign double value to string it gives me exception like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", I check the JSON response in software "postman" there is response its not null. weather_lbl.Text = nObj.Main.temp.ToString();

Comment: @Luc string is like ("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID="+appId+"&q="+city+"");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a LIST of Weather.

you need to do something like

```
foreach(Weather weather in list)
{
Console.WriteLine(weather.description)
}
```